# WFFM Image Uploaded event Sitecore 8

Tags: file-upload, sitecore, sitecore8, web-forms-for-marketers

I have to execute some custom operations once the WFFM File Upload Item is uploaded in Sitecore Media Library.

How I can get the uploaded WFFM media Item in C#.
Which Event/Processor/Pipeline/Config needs to add/update .

I am using below code , it works when i uploaded media manually but not when media comes from Web form Marketer:-

```cs
public class ProcessMedia : UploadProcessor
{
    public void Process(UploadArgs args)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure it's this one, but did you check the `formUploadFile` pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a custom processor to the `formUploadFile` pipeline, the default definition of which can be found in `Sitecore.Forms.config`.

```cs
public class ProcessMedia
{
    public void Process(FormUploadFileArgs args)
    {
        var itemUri = ItemUri.Parse(args.Result);
        var item = Sitecore.Data.Database.GetItem(itemUri);
        // do some stuff...
    }
}
```

And then patch your processor in:

```xml
<sitecore>
  <pipelines>
    <formUploadFile>
      <processor type="MyCustomProject.Forms.Pipelines.ProcessMedia, MyCustomProject.Forms" />
    </formUploadFile>
  </pipelines>  
</sitecore>
```

The processor will be patched in after `Sitecore.Form.Core.Pipelines.FormUploadFile.Save` which is the pipeline responsible for saving files to the Media Library in WFFM.

Comment: thanks @jammyKam ... You always helps and Guide .. :)